# Docker run Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, jenkins-pipeline, pytest

I'm trying to complete my school assignment, which is:

1. fork https://github.com/aaronjolson/flask-pytest-example
2. Write Jenkinsfile, Dockerfile -> Resulting in a new tag on your dockerhub repo
3. Pull docker
4. Build docker
5. Run docker
6. curl localhost:5000 to see results

Currently I'm on stage 5 and I am getting this error when trying to run a docker image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "app.py", line 1, in <module>

from flask import Flask

ImportError: No module named flask
```

Config:

1. Jenkins is working on Debian 9
2. To pull and run docker images using Docker client for Windows
3. Jenkinsfile:

```
it@debian:~/flask-pytest-example$ cat Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    environment {
        registry = "tslaceo/flask-pytest"
        imageName = 'flask-pytest'
        registryCred = 'tslaceo'
        gitProject = "https://github.com/tslaceo/flask-pytest-example.git"
    }
    agent any
    options {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('preparation') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
        stage ('get src from git') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/tslaceo/flask-pytest-example.git'
            }
        }
        stage ('build docker') {
            steps {
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('docker publish') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry( '', registryCred ) {
                        dockerImage.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('cleaning') {
            steps {
                sh "docker rmi $registry:$BUILD_NUMBER"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Dockerfile:

```
it@debian:~/flask-pytest-example$ cat Dockerfile
FROM python
WORKDIR /flask-pytest-example
RUN python --version
RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

5. requirements.txt

```
it@debian:~/flask-pytest-example$ cat requirements.txt
flask
pytest
```

6. ls -la

```
it@debian:~/flask-pytest-example$ ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  5 it it 4096 Apr 27 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 it it 4096 Apr 27 14:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 it it  178 Apr 27 10:32 app.py
-rw-r--r--  1 it it  202 Apr 27 15:06 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 it it  152 Apr 27 12:39 Dockerfile.save
drwxr-xr-x  8 it it 4096 Apr 27 15:06 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 it it   38 Apr 27 10:32 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  2 it it 4096 Apr 27 10:32 handlers
-rw-r--r--  1 it it    0 Apr 27 10:32 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 it it 1147 Apr 27 10:48 Jenkinsfile
-rw-r--r--  1 it it 1071 Apr 27 10:32 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 it it  491 Apr 27 10:32 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 it it   13 Apr 27 10:32 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 it it 4096 Apr 27 10:32 tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `RUN pip freeze ...` line; replace it with `COPY requirements.txt .` to get the copy of that file that's checked in with the rest of your application.

The flow in the Dockerfile you show is

1. Start from a clean, empty Python installation;
2. List all of the packages installed there (that is, nothing) and write into `requirements.txt`;
3. Install all of the packages (that is, nothing) listed in `requirements.txt`.

The `requirements.txt` file should be checked in as part of your application's source code, so if you `COPY` this in instead of regenerating it, it will have packages listed in it and it will be the exact versions of the packages you tested with in your non-Docker virtual environment.

---

I might leave a Jenkins-based build setup as the very last thing in this sequence.  A better approach could be:

1. Build your application using a normal Python virtual environment; no Jenkins, no Docker.

   ```sh
   python3 -m venv venv
   . venv/bin/activate
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   pytest
   ./app.py
   curl http://localhost:5000
   ```
2. Wrap your built, working, tested Python application in a Docker container, using the Dockerfile you show above.

   ```sh
   docker build -t tslaceo/flask-pytest .
   docker run -p 5000:5000 tslaceo/flask-pytest
   curl http://localhost:5000
   ```
3. Wrap this setup in Jenkins.

If something is wrong with your *application* (which is the usual case) the virtual-environment setup will be much easier to debug, and you can use ordinary editors, IDEs, debuggers, *etc.* without any special setup.  If something is wrong with your *packaging* then running `docker build` locally will again be easier to debug and tweak than trying to reproduce it in a CI environment.

Comment: You're right. I've  figured it out. There was a mistake(?) in the source code, when .py file is going to import modules.
Fix:
Take file from `/flask-pytest-example/handlers/routes.py` and copy it in the root application folder, then edit the app.py from `from flask_pytest_example.handlers.routes import configure_routes` to `from routes import configure_routes`.